# Wipe data on wrong password inputs

Tags: security, 4.2-jelly-bean, encryption

I've found several obsolete answers, but this question about situation nowadays:

What's the most robust solution to have the device (Android 4.2-based) protected?

1. Turn on device encryption (there is only built-in storage, no SD-cards)
2. Set up password

But it's all makes not much sense without wiping the data after 10 (or so) wrong password inputs (like iOS does).

So any solutions to wipe after brute-force attempts nowadays?

**UPD**:

I've found there is a method in the API [`setMaximumFailedPasswordsForWipe()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.html#setMaximumFailedPasswordsForWipe%28android.content.ComponentName,%20int%29) but is there a User Interface that calls that method?

**UPD 2**:

Hm, I'm surprised that people don't care of security much, hmmm. That's curious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Autowipe](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vesperaNovus.app.AutowipeFree) for that:

> Use Autowipe to automatically and PERMANENTLY WIPE your internal and external data by doing a factory reset. Enterprise and business users should find this useful! This is meant to be used in case your device gets stolen, misplaced, or lost.
>
> Automatically wipes for: failed passwords to unlock screen, SMS password received, subscriber ID changed (SIM card). Use the new integrated test mode to test all these cases. Locks the screen while wiping.

The app does *not* require root, according to its Playstore description.

[image: Autowipe]
<sup>(click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: Yeah, actually that's the only app I've seen that does what I want. But it's not supported anymore, this makes me worry a bit. Haven't you personally thought of some app like that?

Comment: Not only me (but I'm not a programmer). In his book "Android Forensics and mobile security", forensics specialist (and chief investigator) Andrew Hoog even requests to have such features implemented into the *core system*, where it clearly belongs (though it should be the user deciding whether to *enable* it, he should have the *possibility*). And yes, this is also the only app I have found so far implementing this feature. Mightbe some of the Anti-Theft apps have it as well.